# url rewrite problem wamp

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

for that i have created the url rewrite in the .htaccess inside the login folder ,

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^login$ login.php [NC] # Change feed URL
```

but nothing happened ,

what i do now ,

am using wamp..

Comment: And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: What happens when you enter the /login URL into your browser?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if "AllowOverride" instruction in main "httpd.conf" file allows you to use .htaccess files at all. If not, make it "AllowOverride all" and restart your WampServer.

You may as well follow this tutorial: http://blog.cmstutorials.org/posts/tips-tricks/how-to-make-mod_rewrite-work-on-wamp

Comment: am not did any changes in httpd.conf file, what should i do now

Comment: i got 500 internal server error..i followed posted tutorial link

[click here][1]


  [1]: http://pastebin.com/m7d25e7ba

Answer (score 3):

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /***your-folder-name***/ *//ADD THIS LINE*
RewriteRule  ^login$ login.php [NC] # Change feed URL

Change ***AllowOverride None*** to ***AllowOverride All*** in **httpd.conf** file, then restart wamp.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who had the problem of getting the Url rewrite to work in Wordpress - I followed the instructions from @naivists - changing the httpd.conf and using the WAMP menu to turn on the rewrite.  However I only got the urls working in Wordpress after adding a .htaccss file to the root of my site.  I just copied the basic one from here: https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Note that windows doesn't let you CREATE a .htaccss file (it wants something in front of the dot), but it doesn't mind if you just copy and paste one from somewhere else.